# Repository Query Language select data between data range

Tags: atg

I'm beginner of RQl and I have a product table which have end date for all the products. Now I want to retrieve all products who's end date is null within given time period.

I tried below.

```
endDate IS NULL BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2;
```

But it's not work. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Perhaps your logic is wrong. How can something be both `NULL` and set between two dates? Do you either want the products with an `endDate` of `NULL` or an `endDate` that falls between to dates?

Comment: @radimpe I want products with 'null end date'that falls between to dates.

Comment: But think about your logic. In order to fall between two dates you need to have a date to compare it with so your date cannot be `NULL`.